# Intersection of two actors - Vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I try to indicate the intersection region of two vtkActors. I have three vtkActors in total- two for cones and one for intersection of cones.

I have used vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter to draw the intersection. But I couldn't make it dynamic. When I move the actors to different positions using keyboard interaction which I defined, intersection actor's initial state remains the same. It is not being updated. How can I create and change intersection actor dynamically?

Comment: I did this example based on this project: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/IntersectionPolyDataFilter

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that you are modifying the actors, that is to say only the representation of the polydata. The vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter works on the polydata (that is, it is independent from the representation). If the original polydata are untouched, also the intersection is the same.

On the other hand, if you are updating the polydata (e.g. changing the height of the cone), remember to set the flag Modified() to trigger the update of the vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter